# How to provide fast access to large read only data?

Tags: database

I would like advice regarding how to store approximately 200gb to 1tb of data - that will not change.

The data never has to be updated, but will be queried often and would expect to retrieve data < 100ms.

The data is keyed by a sha256 hash and would only be queried by that key.

The data could be sorted in any way that suits the search process.

My initial ideas are:-

1. Throw it all in a key/value db
2. Partition the data into files based on the key such that a filesystem exists in the format /a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j.dat which contains a smallish number of hashes to read

I've never worked at this scale before, so it might be trivial and obvious to others how to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just load the items once, just load them into any RDBMS and put a clustered index on the sha256 hash. That will give you approximately one disk seek per access because the accesses are at random locations and 1TB of data does not fit into memory. The upper index levels do fit into memory, so you just have one physical IO.

Expect about 10ms of access time.

Very simple and reliable solution.

I don't see the need for partitioning at all because you do not do maintenance. You just perform one bulk load operation. Partitioning makes queries slower, not faster, in most cases.